# Using localStorage to force specific window tab or popup window to reload

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Django project where we assign protocol numbers to documents and the protocol number should appear in a modal message, after the form is submitted and closed. The requested function is that if a file is assigned a protocol number either from the main window or from a popup list of documents it should always present a modal window with the number of the protocol the file has been assigned with.

I have written a jQuery script that -based on certain conditions (page URL contains-or-not specific strings)- [it] sets the localStorage value of **UPDATE** to 1. When that happens, it forces the active window or popup window to reload in order to display a modal with the assigned protocol number.

Unfortunately the reloading doesnt happen as I would like it to happen. It works *most* of the time but there are times where it either:

- forces a second reload of the page or
- doesnt force a reload at all and I have to do it manually or
- (when the script is activated in a popup) it reloads the main page instead of the popup or
- (when the script is activated in a popup) it reloads the popup but the modal message does not appear unless I make a manual reload

For some reason I cannot understand why the script sometimes works and other times doesn't. I would like some feedback, guidance or even an alternative way to do this cause it really boggles my mind and drives me crazy!!!

Here is the script I wrote which is in the project's base.html, at the top of the $(document).ready() function:

```
  var ispopup = '{{ request.get_full_path }}';
  if((ispopup.indexOf('_popup') > -1 ) && (ispopup.indexOf('case') > -1 )){
    console.log('This is a case page in a popup');
    window.setInterval(function(){
      var myupdate = localStorage.getItem('update');
      if(myupdate==1){
        console.log("update before :"+myupdate);
        
          localStorage.setItem("update","0");
          window.location.reload();
        {% if messages %}
          $("#messagesModal").modal('show');
        {% endif %}
        localStorage['papaurl'] = "";      
        console.log("update after :"+myupdate);
        console.log("papaurl :"+localStorage["papaurl"]);
      }
    },2000);    
  } else if((ispopup.indexOf('grandchild') == -1) && (ispopup.indexOf('_popup') == -1 )){
      var thispage;
      if(ispopup.indexOf('library')>-1){thispage = 'library';}
      else if(ispopup.indexOf('case')>-1){thispage = 'case';}
      else{thispage = 'list'}
      console.log('This is a '+thispage+' page in the base page');

      window.setInterval(function(){
        var myupdate = localStorage.getItem('update');
        if(myupdate==1){
          console.log("update before :"+myupdate);
          {% if not messages %}
            localStorage.setItem("update","0");
            window.location.reload();
          {% endif %}
          
          localStorage['papaurl'] = "";      
          console.log("update after :"+myupdate);
          console.log("papaurl :"+localStorage["papaurl"]);
        }
      },2000);
  }
```

The 'messages' variable in the Django tag contains the string of the protocol number which is generated and added in the Python part of this project.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently its something mind twisting or I am lacking the logic/knowledge to make it work. Fortunately I had another option which was mostly Python work:

After the form submits, HttpResponseRedirect the reverse_lazy of the data-update of the app, essentially opening the object with update form, and display the popup there. Since it doesnt need to look for parent pages or whether its a popup window or not, it works consistently. All it needs to do is check for {{ messages }} like so:

```
{% if messages %} $('#messagesModal').modal('show');{% endif %}
```

Note: It did have the problem that when submitting, the page did not forward to the update form immediately (either due to network or server load probably), making it possible to resubmit the form a second time while the first submission was still underway. To prevent this I disabled the submit button when the form is submitted.